# Como eu faço pra colocar hover em uma imagem?

Tags: css3

Como eu faço pra colocar hover em uma imagem.
E quando passado o mouse apareça o hover com texto dentro.

Comment: Bom dia Thayna, você já começou a fazer algo? consegue postar pra gente o seu resultado e explicar até onde você conseguiu evoluir?

Comment: Bom dia, tentei fazer, mas perdi o código não sei como.

Comment: Depois não consigo fazer fazer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é necessário utilizar exatamente uma imagem (falo da tag `img`). Você pode usar uma `div` com `background-image`. Dentro dessa div você vai colocar outra div, com `opacity:0`. Quando passar o mouse sobre a `div`, você fará com que o `houver` da mesma, afete a div com o texto (que será a filha), alterando o valor da mesma para `opacity:1`.

Irei mostrar um exemplo:

```css
.imagem{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvici.jpg);  
  height:300px;
  width:400px;
  background-size:100% auto;
}

.texto{
  padding:20px;
  font-family:Arial;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity .2s linear;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.imagem:hover .texto{
  opacity:1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
  <div class="texto"><h2>Recém casados</h2></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, eu casei. Por isso tá essa foto aí :D

Comment: obg, casal bonito

Comment: Poderia fornecer o motivo do -1. Eu agradeceria. A minha resposta não possui nenhum erro.

Answer (score 2):

O elemento Pai seria a `div` que contém a imagem.

Essa `div` deve ser `position: relative`.

Dentro dela coloquei um `span` com um texto. Esse `span` deve ser `position: absolute` que estará sob alterações relativas ao elemento pai.

Daí é só colocar no centro com as propriedades CSS:

```
.hover-image{
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}
```

OBS: O `bottom` não está acima porquê fiz um efeito para o `span` ficar no meio. Veja a funcionalidade abaixo:

---

```css
.hover-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.hover-image span {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  bottom: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.hover-image:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <span class="texto">Welcome</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Zoom, brilhante. Ficou bom :D

Comment: Olooooooooooooooooco! Fui injustiçado agora! -1 ! -1 !!!!11ONZE!! Passou alguém aqui e negativou todo mundo. Peguem ele !

Comment: Se alguém tiver um bom motivo para justificar os negativos, eu e o Zoom estamos a disposição para corrigir/melhorar os detalhes da resposta.

Comment: obg, ajudou muito

Comment: vc tem site @Zoom?

Comment: Eu não tenho site, nem portfolio... nem nada. Só facebook e instagram